# Renaming the trash command of trash-cli?

Tags: linux, shell, user-interface, command-line-interface

I'm the developer of the trash-cli project.

The trash-cli project is a opensource implementation of the FreeDesktop.org
Trash Specification that provides a command line interface to manage the
trashcan.

Ideally trash-cli provides these commands:

- trash            *(trashes files and directories)*
- trash-empty      *(empty the trashcan(s))*
- trash-list       *(list trashed files)*
- trash-restore    *(restore a trashed file)*

But I must rename the 'trash' command because the name is too generic to let the trash-cli added in Fedora (see full discussion [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=448122))

I chose the 'trash' name because I think is the better name you could use (is short and intuitive), but, as I stated before, I can't use this name.

In any case I think a good choice keep the trash-* form because it exploit the 
shell TAB completion.

In the beginning I was persuaded to rename the 'trash' command in 'trash-file' but I don't like it very much, and as Christoph Bloch [pointed out](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/trash-cli/+bug/310088/comments/3):

> My arguments against "trash-file":
>   * It is not intuitive and therefore unnecessarily difficult to memorise.
>   * It is unnecessarily long.
>   * Every change in the name of programs causes confusion, so the new solution
>     should be a clear improvement (which it isn't).
>   * It is even wrong: Directories can be trashed, too.
>
> Just "trash" was much better.

I collected some ideas for renamng the 'trash' command. Would you like help me
to choose the best one? Do you know a better name?

Here the alternatives (some of them are ugly, I know it, but maybe they help you
to find a better name) :

- trash-put
- trash-put-in
- trash-trash
- trash-throw
- trash-f
- trash-rm
- trash-recycle
- trash-do
- trash-to
- trash-
- trash-now
- trash-!
- trash2
- trash
- trashit
- trash-item
- trash-entry
- trash-elem
- trash-path
- trash-data
- trash-this
- trash-it
- trash-that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trash-put` (for brevity and clarity) or `trash-this` (for ease of typing, as `this` is made up of readily-typed characters -- especially to an OO programmer ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps go the 'UNIX way' and adopt as short a name as possible.

`tf`? - although the objection that it also handles directories remains.

Note that the word 'trash' is perceived in Britain to be an Americanism. I'm not sure about other English speaking countries. Apple clearly didn't care about non-American sensibilities when they named the Trash Can. I guess Red Hat didn't either (or just followed Apple's cue).

Comment: About the 'tf': Thanks, but surely Red Hat will not accept this because it could cause name collision in short time.

Comment: About the Americanism: could you tell me the Britanic counterpart of the verb "trash"?

Comment: When you put something in a "rubbish bin", you are "throwing it away".

Comment: 'tf': agreed, I had not read the bugzilla thread when I suggested it. If maintainers are going to take that attitude, I don't think any user-friendly name will be accepted. Shame.

Comment: @Andrea "trash an object" would be equivalent to "bin an object" in British English, and "a pile of trash" would be "a pile of rubbish"

Comment: using "bin" as a verb is a colloquialism.
The common British way to say "trash an object" would be "throw away an object"

Answer (score 3):

Why not have a single command with different arguments for the actions you want?

trash list
trash empty
 
trash restore {<file>}*

I realize this goes against the UNIX-way in the strictest sense, however, they are all operations on a single object, so I'd make the argument there should be one command for this rather than a group of commands.

---

As far as renaming "trash" to something else, really? Wow, I think "trash" is actually pretty intuitive compared to the alternatives. Some alternatives:

- **trashcan**, or simply **tc**
- **wastebasket**, or simply **wb**

Comment: About the single command, that could be an idea but: it does not exploit the tab completion.

Comment: You can tab complete arguments to a command by providing a bash-completion script. See the bash manual for more details. Most distros have a facility for packages to add their own bash-completion script for completing their arguments.

Comment: @Kamil Kisiel: That is true, but in this case only users with a bash-completion properly installed will take advantage from from tab-completion. Not all systems have the a "bash-completion" package installed.

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

trashcan-put
trashcan-*

Comment: trashcan-put is too long, but trash-put could be a good idea.

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe, Neal Stephenson fan?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a different synonym altogether would be better?

- discard
- fling
- toss
- chuck
- dispose
- scrap
- junk
- recycle

Comment: Some thing like junk, junk-list, junk-restore, junk-empty ? This could be and idea. I hope that the Red Hat reviewer wouldn't reject it because "junk" (or any alternative) is too generic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.

I seems that -put is the preferred one. 
Also in the distributions@lists.freedesktop.org mailing list I received the positive feedback for this command.

Probably the command names will be:

- trash-put (put files (or directories) in the trashcan)
- trash-empty (empty the trashcan(s))
- trash-list (list trashed files)
- trash-restore (restore a trashed file)